# PL/SQL API call/query returns multiple records, how to pass into multiple variables

Tags: oracle, api, plsql, select-into

I have this api_call in oracle sql like this:

```
select sb_transfer_crse.f_query_all('000497') from dual;
```

The response looks like this:

```
SHBTATC_SBGI_CODE SHBTATC_PROGRAM SHBTATC_TLVL_CODE SHBTATC_SUBJ_CODE_TRNS     SHBTATC_CRSE_NUMB_TRNS  SHBTATC_TRNS_TITLE             
------            ------------    --                --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
000497            ......          UG                AAA                        010                     Acad Achievement Pre-College   
000497            ......          UG                AAA                        050                     Semester Survival              
000497            ......          UG                AAA                        070                     Special Topics                 
000497            ......          UG                AAA                        071                     Special Topics                 
000497            ......          UG                AAA                        072                     Special Topics                 
000497            ......          UG                AAA                        073                     Special Topics
```

I am trying to pass the response data into variables either to handle one a time in a loop or if possible take them all and export to a temp/new table

What i have so far looks like this:

```
Declare
--variables for query
VAR_p_sbgi_code shbtatc.shbtatc_sbgi_code%TYPE;

--Variables for Data being returned

VAR_r_sbgi_code               shbtatc.shbtatc_sbgi_code%TYPE;
VAR_r_program                 shbtatc.shbtatc_program%TYPE;
VAR_r_tlvl_code               shbtatc.shbtatc_tlvl_code%TYPE;
VAR_r_subj_code_trns          shbtatc.shbtatc_subj_code_trns%TYPE;
VAR_r_crse_numb_trns          shbtatc.shbtatc_crse_numb_trns%TYPE;
VAR_r_trns_title              shbtatc.shbtatc_trns_title%TYPE;

Begin
select sb_transfer_crse.f_query_all(p_sbgi_code     => VAR_p_sbgi_code)
        INTO VAR_r_sbgi_code,VAR_r_program,VAR_r_tlvl_code,VAR_r_subj_code_trns,VAR_r_crse_numb_trns,VAR_r_trns_title
From Dual;
End;
```

The problem is I am used to dealing with getting one result/response, not 6. and I'm not sure how to loop through the results?

Any help would be appreciated.

This is the function:

```
Function f_query_all(p_sbgi_code shbtatc.shbtatc_sbgi_code%TYPE,
                     p_program   shbtatc.shbtatc_program%TYPE DEFAULT NULL)
  RETURN transfer_crse_ref
```

This is what transfer_crse_ref is:

```
transfer_crse_ref

TYPE transfer_crse_ref IS REF CURSOR RETURN transfer_crse_rec;
Entity cursor variable type
```

and this is what transfer_crse_rec looks like:

```
transfer_crse_rec

TYPE transfer_crse_rec IS RECORD (
  r_sbgi_code               shbtatc.shbtatc_sbgi_code%TYPE,
  r_program                 shbtatc.shbtatc_program%TYPE,
  r_tlvl_code               shbtatc.shbtatc_tlvl_code%TYPE,
  r_subj_code_trns          shbtatc.shbtatc_subj_code_trns%TYPE,
  r_crse_numb_trns          shbtatc.shbtatc_crse_numb_trns%TYPE,
  r_term_code_eff_trns      shbtatc.shbtatc_term_code_eff_trns%TYPE,
  r_trns_title              shbtatc.shbtatc_trns_title%TYPE,
  r_trns_low_hrs            shbtatc.shbtatc_trns_low_hrs%TYPE,
  r_trns_high_hrs           shbtatc.shbtatc_trns_high_hrs%TYPE,
  r_trns_review_ind         shbtatc.shbtatc_trns_review_ind%TYPE,
  r_tast_code               shbtatc.shbtatc_tast_code%TYPE,
  r_trns_catalog            shbtatc.shbtatc_trns_catalog%TYPE,
  r_tgrd_code_min           shbtatc.shbtatc_tgrd_code_min%TYPE,
  r_group                   shbtatc.shbtatc_group%TYPE,
  r_group_primary_ind       shbtatc.shbtatc_group_primary_ind%TYPE,
  r_protect_ind             shbtatc.shbtatc_protect_ind%TYPE,
  r_crse_desc               shbtatc.shbtatc_crse_desc%TYPE,
  r_user_id                 shbtatc.shbtatc_user_id%TYPE,
  r_data_origin             shbtatc.shbtatc_data_origin%TYPE,
  r_internal_record_id      gb_common.internal_record_id_type);
Business Entity record type
```

Comment: Use a FOR-LOOP cursor to iterate over dataset

Comment: Can you post the declaration of `f_query_all`?  It doesn't make sense that a query against `dual` would return multiple rows.  My guess is that `f_query_all` is returning a `sys_refcursor` or a collection and that there is a missing step between the query you show and the results you show where some other application is formatting the results.

Comment: @JustinCave added the requested info, i think

Comment: @alvalongo that is what i would normally when i pull data from a table, but i didnt know if that would work for an api call like this?

Comment: @JustinCave i see what you mean, it does look it returns the results into a cursor with the transfer_crse_ref piece

Answer (score 0):

Ok with the help of @justinCave when they mentioned the ref_cursor i was able to figure out a solution that gives me the results in a way I can get the data to variables:

```
declare
  symbol_cursor  BANINST1.sb_transfer_crse.transfer_crse_ref;
  symbol_record  BANINST1.sb_transfer_crse.transfer_crse_rec;
begin
  symbol_cursor := sb_transfer_crse.f_query_all(p_sbgi_code     => '000497');
  loop
    fetch symbol_cursor into symbol_record;
    exit when symbol_cursor%notfound;

    -- Do something with each record here, e.g.:
    dbms_output.put_line(symbol_record.r_sbgi_code|| ',' ||symbol_record.r_program|| ',' ||symbol_record.r_tlvl_code|| ',' ||symbol_record.r_subj_code_trns|| ',' ||symbol_record.r_crse_numb_trns|| ',' ||symbol_record.r_term_code_eff_trns|| ',' ||symbol_record.r_trns_title|| ',' ||symbol_record.r_trns_low_hrs|| ',' ||symbol_record.r_trns_high_hrs|| ',' ||symbol_record.r_trns_review_ind|| ',' ||symbol_record.r_tast_code|| ',' ||symbol_record.r_trns_catalog|| ',' ||symbol_record.r_tgrd_code_min|| ',' ||symbol_record.r_group|| ',' ||symbol_record.r_group_primary_ind|| ',' ||symbol_record.r_protect_ind|| ',' ||symbol_record.r_crse_desc|| ',' ||symbol_record.r_user_id|| ',' ||symbol_record.r_data_origin|| ',' ||symbol_record.r_internal_record_id);

  end loop;

  CLOSE symbol_cursor;

end;
```